# React.js - Getting an index of an element from <'div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a task manager app with React.js and I want to use Drag&Drop function in order to throw an element into the trash can. I am able to use (index) in .forEach, but not sure how to do it inside the trashcan <'div>
Currently I am using array of categories in order to store the tasks depending on their category, but I want to know if there is a way of using .splice() on this situation.

Video of my app for better understanding : https://youtu.be/ug9jzjdbF-I

My state is just an empty where I am pushing data from my "submit" button.

```
this.state = {tasks:[]}
```

Empty array of categories (busy,todo,removed,complete) to show the state of the task.

```
  let tasksInBoard = {
      todo : [],
      busy : [],
      complete:[],
      removed : []
    }
```

onDragStart function:

```
  onDragStart = (e,id) => {
    console.log("dragstart ",id);
    e.dataTransfer.setData("id",id);
  }
```

And .forEach to put them on the arrays depending on their category.

```
   this.state.tasks.forEach((t,index)=>{
      tasksInBoard[t.category].push(
                <CreatedTask
                  index={index}
                  key = {index}
                  member={t.member}
                  todo={t.toDo}
                  dod={t.dod}
                  time={t.time}
                  draggable = "true"
                  onDragStart={(e)=> this.onDragStart(e,(t.dod+t.member+t.toDo+t.time))}
                  styling = {t.styling}
                />  
            )
      }
    )
```

My trash can code div :

```
<div className="trashCan"
   onDrop={(e)=>this.onDrop(e,"removed")}
   onDragOver={(e)=>this.onDragOver(e)}>
      <p>this is trahscan</p>
  </div>
```